# HTML 5 Bootstrap google maps

Tags: html5, google-maps, iframe, bootstrap

Estou com um problema que o mapa não carrega certamente, mas é somente o segundo mapa, os outros carregam normalmente.

```
<!--Joinville -->
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <iframe width=100% height=50% frameborder=1px  src="http://maps.google.com.br/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=ilpea+do+brasil&amp;sll=-14.093957,-50.449219&amp;sspn=67.156049,158.027344&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=-26.320537,-48.839979&amp;spn=0.009617,0.012875&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"></iframe>        
        </div>
    </div>
<!--Jundiai -->
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
    <!--Este aqui não carrega-->    <iframe width=100% height=50% frameborder=1px src="https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Ilpea+do+Brasil/@-23.1857027,-46.8999944,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x94cf25b8b4e5eda9:0xe3ae249fbe54e50c!8m2!3d-23.1857076!4d-46.8978057"></iframe>

        </div>
    </div>
<!--Maracanaú -->
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <iframe width=100% height=50% frameborder=1px src="https://www.google.com.br/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=pt&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Av.+Parque+Sul,+2252+-+Distrito+Industrial+I,+Maracana%C3%BA+-+CE&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=+AV.+PARQUE+SUL,+2252C+-+DISTRITO+INDUSTRIAL&amp;sll=-26.26169,-48.966474&amp;sspn=1.018484,1.349945&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Av.+Parque+Sul,+2252+-+Distrito+Industrial+I,+Maracana%C3%BA+-+Cear%C3%A1,+61939-000&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=-3.869618,-38.615613&amp;output=embed"></iframe>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Em resposta ao comentario do luã. Eu usei este exemplo aqui https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search?hl=pt-br, ele funciona mas somente quando ele está sozinho. exemplo:

```
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCsu3mUlmJYTi1oww1H5KrpkpRskkLmG_E&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

mas se eu deixo ele em uma div usando o bootstrap ele não funciona. simplismente não aparece nada. exemplo:

```
  <body>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCsu3mUlmJYTi1oww1H5KrpkpRskkLmG_E&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta fazer  com a Google Maps API evite utilizar o iFrame
https://developers.google.com/maps/web/?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 1):

Adicione `;output=embed"` no final do src do iframe.

Observe que os dois que funcionam possuem isso no final :)

Answer (score 1):

Seu código de incorporação do segundo mapa estava com erro. Eu abri o Google maps:

Eu fiz isto acessando o endereço: `https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Ilpea+do+Brasil/@-23.1857027,-46.8999944,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x94cf25b8b4e5eda9:0xe3ae249fbe54e50c!8m2!3d-23.1857076!4d-46.8978057`

Cliquei em `Compartilhar` e depois em `Incorporar Mapa`.  Com o código gerado eu peguei somente a parte que fica dentro do `src` e substitui pelo código do seu `src`.

Resumindo:

Pegue o código:

`https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Ilpea+do+Brasil/@-23.1857027,-46.8999944,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x94cf25b8b4e5eda9:0xe3ae249fbe54e50c!8m2!3d-23.1857076!4d-46.8978057`

E substitui por:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3667.574975563346!2d-46.8999943850292!3d-23.185707584870737!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94cf25b8b4e5eda9%3A0xe3ae249fbe54e50c!2sIlpea+do+Brasil!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1467641307151
```

Vai ficar assim:

```
<!--Joinville -->
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width=100% height=50% frameborder=1px  src="http://maps.google.com.br/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=ilpea+do+brasil&amp;sll=-14.093957,-50.449219&amp;sspn=67.156049,158.027344&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=-26.320537,-48.839979&amp;spn=0.009617,0.012875&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"></iframe>        
    </div>
</div>
<!--Jundiai -->
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6">
<!--Este aqui não carrega-->    <iframe width=100% height=50% frameborder=1px src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3667.574975563346!2d-46.8999943850292!3d-23.185707584870737!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94cf25b8b4e5eda9%3A0xe3ae249fbe54e50c!2sIlpea+do+Brasil!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1467641307151"></iframe>

    </div>
</div>
<!--Maracanaú -->
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width=100% height=50% frameborder=1px src="https://www.google.com.br/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=pt&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Av.+Parque+Sul,+2252+-+Distrito+Industrial+I,+Maracana%C3%BA+-+CE&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=+AV.+PARQUE+SUL,+2252C+-+DISTRITO+INDUSTRIAL&amp;sll=-26.26169,-48.966474&amp;sspn=1.018484,1.349945&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Av.+Parque+Sul,+2252+-+Distrito+Industrial+I,+Maracana%C3%BA+-+Cear%C3%A1,+61939-000&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=-3.869618,-38.615613&amp;output=embed"></iframe>

    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

[Veja em funcionamento aqui](http://codepen.io/wendell_chrys/pen/GqEmrZ).

Answer (score 1):

Clique na URL do seu [iframe](https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Ilpea+do+Brasil/@-23.1857027,-46.8999944,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x94cf25b8b4e5eda9:0xe3ae249fbe54e50c!8m2!3d-23.1857076!4d-46.8978057), no menu lateral, clique no link compartilhar com ícone azul no box que abrir, navegue até a aba "incorporar mapa", pegue o link do iframe do Google e edite conforme abaixo:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width="100%" height="50%" frameborder="1px" src="http://maps.google.com.br/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=ilpea+do+brasil&amp;sll=-14.093957,-50.449219&amp;sspn=67.156049,158.027344&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=-26.320537,-48.839979&amp;spn=0.009617,0.012875&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed" allowfullscreen></iframe>        
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width="100%" height="50%" frameborder="1px" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3667.574975563346!2d-46.8999943850292!3d-23.185707584870737!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94cf25b8b4e5eda9%3A0xe3ae249fbe54e50c!2sIlpea+do+Brasil!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1467642838431" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <iframe width="100%" height="50%" frameborder="1px" src="https://www.google.com.br/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=pt&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Av.+Parque+Sul,+2252+-+Distrito+Industrial+I,+Maracana%C3%BA+-+CE&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=+AV.+PARQUE+SUL,+2252C+-+DISTRITO+INDUSTRIAL&amp;sll=-26.26169,-48.966474&amp;sspn=1.018484,1.349945&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Av.+Parque+Sul,+2252+-+Distrito+Industrial+I,+Maracana%C3%BA+-+Cear%C3%A1,+61939-000&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=-3.869618,-38.615613&amp;output=embed" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```